# When using URLs then alignment is breaks

Tags: org-mode, align, url

Given:

Ubunut 22.04 LTS

Emacs 28.1

Here my org file:

[image]

As you can see then in the column "Task" has text then alignment is good.

But when has a hyper link (URL) then alignment breaks.

Why?

P.S. Here details when cursor is on the text:

```
             position: 412 of 1538 (27%), column: 44
            character: s (displayed as s) (codepoint 115, #o163, #x73)
              charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x73
               script: latin
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Left-to-right (strong), a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 73" or "C-x 8 RET LATIN SMALL LETTER S"
          buffer code: #x73
            file code: #x73 (encoded by coding system undecided-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    ftcrhb:-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-20-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x56)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN SMALL LETTER S
  general-category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
  decomposition: (115) ('s')

There is an overlay here:
 From 368 to 481
  face                 hl-line
  priority             -50
  window               #<window 7 on test.org>


There are text properties here:
  face                 org-table
  fontified            t
```

Here details when cursor is on the url:

```
          position: 526 of 1538 (34%), column: 45
            character: t (displayed as t) (codepoint 116, #o164, #x74)
              charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x74
               script: latin
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Left-to-right (strong), a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 74" or "C-x 8 RET LATIN SMALL LETTER T"
          buffer code: #x74
            file code: #x74 (encoded by coding system undecided-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    ftcrhb:-DAMA-Ubuntu Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-20-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x57)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN SMALL LETTER T
  general-category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
  decomposition: (116) ('t')

There is an overlay here:
 From 481 to 594
  face                 hl-line
  priority             -50
  window               #<window 7 on test.org>


There are text properties here:
  face                 org-link
  font-lock-multiline  t
  fontified            t
  help-echo            "LINK: https://some_my_url/issues/19510"
  htmlize-link         (:uri "https://some_my_url/issues/19510")
  keymap               [Show]
  mouse-face           highlight

[back]
```

P.P.S
On Linux Mint 20 (on another computer) I has same Emacs version and same Emacs configuration. But on Linux Mint no problem with alignment on org file.

Comment: Because your links seem to be using a different font (or at least a different font width) than the rest of the text in the table. Use `C-u C-x =` on a character in the link and a character *not* in the link and compare the faces that each uses.

Comment: @NickD I updated my post

Comment: Here's [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72892/how-to-use-fonts-for-normal-text-for-org-mode-tables) about faces that might help. Basically, you have to use `describe-face` on each face (`org-table` and `org-link` here) and find out why they are using differrent fonts.

Comment: @NickD On Linux Mint 20  (on another computer) I has same Emacs version and same Emacs configuration. But on Linux Mint no problem with alignment on org file.

Comment: You probably don't have all the fonts on Ubuntu that you have on Mint and Emacs is falling back to fonts that you have. It's only the Emacs configuration that has to be the same: the *system* configuration is important too.

Comment: This should say: "It's *NOT* only the Emacs configuration..."

Comment: @NickD Do you mean, that I need to install on Ubuntu additional fonts?

Comment: If you want the behavior to be identical in the two systems, then you will probably have to do that on the Ubuntu system to match what the Mint system has. Alternatively, you can choose a different font as default (one that both systems have available), in order to make their behaviors identical.